# Check my relational algebra against SQL?

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

```
SELECT * FROM Schools JOIN Masts on Schools.City = Masts.City
```

becomes:

```
Schools ⋊ Masts = σSchools.city = masts.city SCHOOLS X MASTS
```

Am i correct with this? hopefully someones around for a quick answer in the next 20 mins or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a copy of this book: [Applied Mathematics for Database Professionals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00EQSTZZS), you really ought to check it out. It helped me immensely with these kinds of problems. (The hardcover is a real find, but there's only one copy and it's way too expensive—but there are soft-cover versions and the e-book format available, too.)

Also, check out this very good [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Natural_join_.28.E2.8B.88.29) article on Relational Algebra.

The Wikipedia article above shows that what you're trying to accomplish is called an [*equijoin*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#.CE.B8-join_and_equijoin), which is a specialized form of θ-join. Using your example above, you should have output the following:

Let:

- Schools → S;
- Masts → M
- θ → =

Then:

S ⨝<sub>θ</sub> M → σ<sub>θ</sub>(S × M)

In the book *Applied Mathematics for Database Professionals*, the authors use "lower-level" relational algebra to define a SQL `JOIN`. The definition follows:

Let:

- Schools → S
- Masts → M

Then:

{ s ∪ m | s∈S ∧ m∈M ∧ s(City) = m(City) }

The authors further go on to give a general definition of the above using the operator ⊗ (perhaps it was easier for them to publish that symbol rather than using the traditional ⨝ symbol— doesn't make sense though, as they did use Latex—but I'll stick with the traditional symbol):

R ⨝<sub>θ</sub> T → { r ∪ t | r∈R ∧ t∈T ∧ "*r* and *t* are compatible" }

*Compatibility* is "user-defined", hence ⨝<sub>θ</sub>. θ could be any relational operator, <, >, etc.When testing for two attributes being equal as being the result of a successful join condition, then θ → =, and as stated previously, this is a specialized θ-join known as an *equijoin*.

So, after all that:

R ⨝<sub>θ</sub> T → σ<sub>θ</sub>(R × T) → { r ∪ t | r∈R ∧ t∈T ∧ "*r* and *t* are compatible" }

I know this is much later than 20 minutes from when you posted, but hopefully someone finds it helpful.